# Circuit constraint respecting the order of the next n jobs / jobs on each machine starting at 0

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools, job-shop-scheduling, cp-sat

I am working on a scheduling problem in OR-Tools using the CP-SAT solver.

I'm working with
python but I managed to rebuild this solution as starting point:
[Optimal way to ensure optional intervals are consecutive in OR-Tools](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/optimal-way-to-ensure-optional-intervals-are-consecutive-in-or-tools?rq=1&newreg=f0ec614e71be4a8986863bc279b3175f)

Just like in that problem I also have the constraint, that the jobs are consecutive. This works already.

My first problem is really easy in my mind, but somehow I cant make it work: the first job on each machine MUST start at 0.

Second problem: lets say I produce n colors of the same product. Every one of these $n$ colors has a maximum $i$, which is the maximum number of jobs of the same color I can build in sequence on the same machine.

My solution pretty much depends on my `x[job,machine]` dict where `x[job,machine]` is true if job is performed on machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 1) Look at [this literal](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/86d4c543f717fa8716a9d66c25143660668bf825/examples/python/jobshop_ft06_distance_sat.py#L91) in the jobshop with setup times. You just need to add:

```
model.Add(start_of_job == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(start_lit)
```

For 2) For each color, add for each job a variable ranging from 0 to max_sequence_length for this color.

For each [arc](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/86d4c543f717fa8716a9d66c25143660668bf825/examples/python/jobshop_ft06_distance_sat.py#L91), you know if job_i has the same color as job_j. If true, the

```
model.Add(sequence_length[color][j] = sequence_length[color][i] + 1).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
```

else

```
model.Add(sequence_length[color_i][j] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
model.Add(sequence_length[color_j][j] == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
```

And do not forget to initialize all sequence lengths vars with the `start_lit` literal.